# How can I calculate the absolute value of a variable in JMeter during performance testing?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

How to get magnitude or absolute value of a variable in jmeter?

I didn't found any function to find the absolute value of a variable in JMeter.
Like if a variable holds the value -12 I want to store 12 instead of storing -12 in that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use i.e. __groovy() function in order to replace the negative variable with the absolute value of the integer.

Something like:

```
${__groovy(vars.put('myVar'\, Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(vars.get('myVar'))) as String),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Alternative solution would be using [__strReplace() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup), it can be installed as a part of [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

```
${__strReplace(${myVar},-,,myVar)}
```

[image]